# Matrix multiplication optimization: Loop tiling

Tags: c, caching, optimization, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to optimize the multiplication of 2 1024x1024 matrices by tiling the loops. I found that using block sizes of 128 and 64 gave me by far the best results but I only obtained those numbers by guess and check. And when trying to use the same block sizes for 2000x2000 matrices the results are far from ideal. Could anyone point me towards being able to logically solve which tile sizes are best when trying to optimize matrix multiplication?

Comment: How do you know the results are far from ideal in the 2000x2000 case?

Comment: Because its for an assignment and Im given what I should be able to optimize it to. Im not asking for an answer just a point in the right direction because I thought tile size was dependant on cache size but apparently theres so much more to it.

Comment: The associativity of your cache can also affect the results see [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29). IMO, there is no single "optimal" tile size that will work for all sizes of matrix multiplication.

Comment: refere to: http://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf page 50 gives some proper recomendtions. hope this helps. bw